# XAML editing options

Tags: wpf, xaml

I use Visual Studio 2010 for WPF development of desktop apps.  I edit my XAML with the visual editor, often tweaking it manually.  My code-behind is C#.   I haven't had any particular problems with this arrangement.

What are the advantages of Expression Blend over Visual Studio for editing XAML?    Why is Expression Blend so expensive (it's more expensive than I paid for Visual Studio!!)   Are there other full-featured XAML editors which are cheaper?   (I'm not talking about free ones like kaxaml - those are too limited)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expression Blend does not come stand alone any longer; it is part of [Expression Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/Purchase.aspx) which also provides SketchFlow, Design, and a couple of other tools.

Visual Studio is geared towards the development aspect while Expression Blend is geared towards the design aspect. Building animations and performing binding all within the UI of Expression Blend is possible; not forcing you to modify the XAML by hand. You can however modify the XAML directly within Blend as you can the C# code behind as well.

I typically use Blend to lay out the UI and then make use of Visual Studio for the code behind and tweaking of the XAML. Blend is definitely a nice tool to have within your tool belt and I would recommend you download the [trial](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/try-it/) to get a better understanding on the offering.

Answer (score 1):

I find that the main advantage of Blend is that the UI makes it very, very easy to create complex animations and transitions - really gorgeous user experience things - but you need to spend some time 'learning' Blend to do it. To write the XAML in Visual Studio to create the same effects would be much more difficult - Blend does it much quicker, and you can preview the results instantly. It's not easy (if it's even possible - I've honestly not tried the more demanding stuff) with Visual Studio.